# xamarin - closing activity from fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, xamarin.android

I have my fragment that will display transactions. It is a recyclerView. When I click one transaction from fragment, it will be displayed in a form with corresponding values where I can delete or update it.

How can I close the activity through fragment where my fragment connected before I start another activity?

Comment: Can you please share you fragment code? what did you accomplish so far? what did you try? what you're asking a bit blurry..

Comment: I posted my answer for your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not updating my question nor giving an answer. After trials, I just thought of passing the activity on fragment constructor then close the activity using activity.Finish(); when I click on item in recycler view

```
    private Expense_Objects expenseObject;
    private Denomination_Objects denominationObject;
    private Activity activity;

    /// <summary>
    /// Fragment for Petty Cash
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="expenseObject">Expense Object</param>
    /// <param name="denominationObject">Denomination Object</param>
    /// <param name="activity">Activity where fragment will reside</param>
    public Fragment_PettyCash(Expense_Objects expenseObject, 
            Denomination_Objects denominationObject, Activity activity)
    {
        this.pcExpenseObject = pcExpenseObject;
        this.denominationObject = denominationObject;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Setting up recyclerView
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="recyclerView">recyclerView</param>
    private void setUpRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
    {
        recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.Context));
        recyclerView.SetAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(recyclerView.Context, 
                expenseObject.payeeList, expenseObject.totalAmountList));

        recyclerView.SetItemClickListener((rv, position, view) =>
            {
                //doing other stuffs

                Context context = view.Context;

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(UpdateDeleteExpense));

                intent.PutExtra(IntentExtras.denominationSerialized, 
                        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(denominationObject));

                intent.PutExtra(IntentExtras.pettyCashExpenseSerialized, 
                        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(expenseObject));

                context.StartActivity(intent);

                activity.Finish();
            }
        );
    }
```